# Привязка к состоянию клавиши Caps Lock MVVM WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть `ViewModel` для формы авторизации. В ней реализовано **INPC**-свойство `IsCapsLockOn`. Оно биндится к `TextBox` на `View` (`TextBox` отображается, когда аксессор свойства возвращает *true*). Вопрос в том, когда вызывать метод `OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)`, и к какому событию привязываться, чтобы `IsCapsLockOn` изменялось при каждом нажатии на *Caps Lock*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683620/c-sharp-actively-detect-lock-keys - событий как таковых нет, можно либо проверять по таймеру, либо хукать клавиатурные нажатия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выставить binding напрямую не выйдет, но можно обойтись и без импорта win32, как посоветовали выше.

Если вам нужно реагировать на изменение состояния Caps lock только при фокусе в textbox, будет достаточным подписаться на событие UIElement.KeyDown: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.uielement.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx

В его обработчике (который будет в code behind страницы\контрола) нужно проверить, какая клавиша пришла. Для этого посмотрите свойство
SystemKey у класса KeyEventArgs, оно содержит значение CapsLock: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.input.key(v=vs.110).aspx

В случае прохождения проверки останется только обновить binding. Для этого сначала достаньте binding expression у тектсбокса. 
Скорее всего байндинг на текст вам не подойдет, но я оставил его как пример. 
Можете вообще забиндиться на другой элемент, невидимый, и обновлять его binding expression

```
var bindingExpression = textBox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
```

А затем обновите его

```
bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
```

Если непонятно, пишите, дополню рабочей реализацией